# Getting , Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page After adding

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

this two steps before ***browser.get***

Comment: Add the steps after `browser.get()`. And `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;` is deprecated

Comment: What language, what have you tried, what errors are you getting?  Can you paste some code.

Comment: I am getting  [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 6abef9f2-9f51-4db3-9df7-ff7c256fa361 (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
console.error: BroadcastService:
  receivedBroadcastMessage: handler for
  remote-settings/monitor_changes
  threw error:
  Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource..
  Stack:
    remoteSettingsFunction/remoteSettings.pollChanges@resource://services-settings/remote-settings.js:721:13
 while running in firefox, Firefox driver version is 0.24 ,browser version is 63